# Does large text datatypes reserves storage on disk?

Tags: mysql, memory, storage

I'm design an DB for an app, in a table there is a column MEDIUMTEXT which according to mysql doc can storage on disk upto 16MB.

So my question is if I'm storing a text of 1Mb in this column, will it still reserves 16MB storage/block on disk for this particular record.

And also while reading all columns of multiple rows at once i.e 100 rows, what impact will have on memory and CPU usage for reading such large size storage columns?

Answer (score 2):

For **InnoDB** (not NDB), the following applies

**Short answer:**  1MB in a `MEDIUMTEXT` will take at least 20 bytes in-record plus about 65 16KB blocks off-record.

**Long answer:**

- `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns (of any size) are *usually* stored "off-record".
- If the contents of the column is "small", it *may* be stored "in-record" with the rest of the columns, like the other datatypes.  (It would take a *long* discussion to spell out the situations; see `ROW_FORMAT`.)
- When it is off-record, 0 to 767 bytes are stored on-record, together with a 20-byte pointer.
- The pointer effectively points to the block(s) containing the rest of the text or blob.
- `MEDIUMTEXT` and `MEDIUMBLOB` need a 3-byte length in addition to *up to* 16 *megabytes* (not "characters).
- 16MB is not reserved; it is variable length.  The minimum is a few bytes (null bit, length, etc); the max is more than 16MB (pointer, text/blob, blocking overhead).
- The only(?) difference between `TEXT` and `BLOB` is whether the bytes adhere to character set rules.
- The only(?) differences between `VARCHAR/VARBINARY` and `TEXT/BLOB` is the size limitation rules and whether an `INDEX` can apply to it without "prefixing".

The **other question**...

> And also while reading all columns of multiple rows at once i.e 100 rows, what impact will have on memory and CPU usage for reading such large size storage columns?

100MB will take I/O, memory, and some CPU.

- If the cache (buffer_pool) is cold, then a lot of I/O to fetch the data.
- If cached already, then no I/O.
- Memory:  the resultset will be big, but will probably be streamed to the client.
- CPU:  Not much.
- But can your *client* handle such a large resultset?

It is *usually* better to do more processing in SQL than to shovel huge amounts of data to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Mot eactly, see [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)

> TEXT and BLOB columns are implemented differently in NDB; each row in a TEXT column is made up of two separate parts. One of these is of fixed size (256 bytes), and is actually stored in the original table. The other consists of any data in excess of 256 bytes, which is stored in a hidden table. The rows in this second table are always 2000 bytes long. This means that the size of a TEXT column is 256 if size <= 256 (where size represents the size of the row); otherwise, the size is 256 + size + (2000 × (size − 256) % 2000).

As you can see it save 256 Bytes if you have equal or less than 256 bytes.
And if you have more than 256 bytes mysql reserved 200 Bytes blocks till it can store all data

Comment: This answer is limited to MySQL's "NDB cluster".

Comment: I have a table with a TEXT field that takes about 120 bytes per record, so not 256 or 200

Comment: So why using a text field a varchsr or a fixed sie char would be better